# Trying to set checkbox visibility programmatically by referencing another checkbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make the checkboxs on the form visible if the field in table with same same as checkbox prefixed with 'm' is set to true. 
The function goes through all the controls on the form, when it gets to a myCheckbox it finds the name of the checkbox that controls it by adding an 'm' to it's name. The value of mControl is set on another form, via a checkbox. So the first form sets the display to true or false on the checkboxes of the second form.

```
Private Function Display_To_Screen(ByVal DS As DataSet, ByVal Table As String, ByVal Row As String, ByVal ParentControl As Control) As Boolean

    Dim mctl As Object
    Dim ctl As Object

    Try
        For Each ctl In ParentControl.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is MyCheckBox Then

                mctl = Get_mFieldName(ctl)

                If IsDBNull(mctl) Then
                    ctl.Visible = False
                Else
                    ctl.Visible = True
                End If

            ElseIf ctl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                ' this ctl is itself a container so we will call this function 
                ' from within itself.
                Call Display_To_Screen(DS, Table, Row, ctl)
            End If

        Next ctl


Public Function Get_mFieldName(ByVal ctl As Control) As String
    'Gets the field name of the mControlName so can find if that value is TRUE to enable visibility on control

    Get_mFieldName = "m" & Right(ctl.Name, Len(ctl.Name) - 3)
End Function
```

Comment: First and foremost, have you stepped through this with the debugger to ensure that you are actually executing this section of code? And if so, did the variables hold what you expected as you moved through it?

Comment: I would also look at simplifying that code to only loop through your controls.  `for each ctl in ParentControls.Controls.OfType(Of MyCheckBox)()` will only include controls that are of the type MyCheckBox.

Comment: In the locals windows it says string.Concat returned "mCorrect" String , which is the right name for the field in the DB, which is returend by the function Get_mFieldName. The variable mctl is saying undeclared or inaccessible and it skips to the True statement and carries on.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with the isDBNull and why are you declaring mctl as an object that is then set to a string value from the function return?

Comment: What I trying to is look through the Dataset, and find the string name of the control object mCTL, check to see if it is NULL, probably need to check if it is not TRUE really, and if it has been picked set the visibilty on the 'calling' control.

Comment: @CharlesMay to your second comment, the code needs to include other types of controls as well because it calls itself recursively if it encounters a container with other controls in it.

Comment: Yep. Just skips everything actually if try to use ofType(ofmyCheckbox)

Comment: @mabees you need to include the desired behavior and what is not working in your question. As of now it only includes "I'm trying to do...". What is the actual issue here?

Comment: How to make ISDBNULL check to see if another value not the calling control is NULL

Comment: @mabees a couple things: don't use ByVal on the DataSet because it will make a copy every time you call it (and since this is called recursively it is very inefficient). also I don't quite understand your last comment.

Comment: This is working now with Get_mFieldName returning an object, all my checkboxes on the secnd form are now invisible. Thanks for the tip about ByVal, I wil try making it By Ref.

Comment: @mabees just leave out ByVal / ByRef for all your parameters. The default is usually what you need and it's better to set it only when you deviate from the typical use case.

Comment: I don't see why you need the function at all when you could just set the value like the function does. Also, your function will always set Get_mFieldName to "m" + something. Even if the name of the control is NULL, it will still return just "m". So why are you checking to see if it is NULL? It will never be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough info and I don't have enough points to comment and ask questions.
 
 
Allot of that code is unnecessary. Here is a template for you.

Simply set the visibility based on the results of CanMyControlBeVisable(). 
 
 Your logic in Get_mFieldName() will ALWAYS return a string; it's never going to be NULL. Thus the visibility will always be TRUE.

```
Private Function Display_To_Screen(DS As DataSet, Table As String, Row As String, ParentControl As Control) As Boolean
    Try
        For Each ctl As Control In ParentControl.Controls

            If ctl.Controls.Count Then Display_To_Screen(DS, Table, Row, ctl)

            If Not TypeOf ctl Is MyCheckBox Then Continue For

            ctl.Visible = CanMyControlBeVisable(ctl)

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Do something
    End Try

    'This part is missing from OP's code sample.

    'Are you returning a value?
    'If not, change this to a Sub()

    'Are you using the parameters "DataSet", "Table", and "Row" somewhere down here?
    'If not, delete them from the function definition. 

End Function

Private Function CanMyControlBeVisable(p_ctl As Control) As Boolean
    'Do your work here
    'Return the result as TRUE or FALSE
End Function
```